# How do I automate dotfiles setup / management with ansible?

Tags: git, ansible, zsh, oh-my-zsh, dotfiles

Bootstrapping dotfiles setup via scripts (bash, zsh) eventually gets complicated. How can Ansible be leveraged to automate setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- Clone the repo: [ellaqezi/dotfiles](https://github.com/ellaqezi/dotfiles) on github into `$dotfiles_dir`
- [Install Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html)
- Run the playbook (the `become` password is your user's password)

  ```
  cd $dotfiles_dir/ansible
  ansible-playbook -i hosts setup-dotfiles.yml --ask-become-pass
  ```

Do also check out the dotfiles utilities listed in https://dotfiles.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider alternative to Ansible as it does not come handy for dotfiles. Probably a better option to manage dotfile is to use **Pearl**:
https://github.com/pearl-core/pearl